# didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame for certain URL but works fine in Safari

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I've got an odd issue where a certain domain fails to load in a WKWebView. It gives an error:

`WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=-1200`

Which I believe is complaining about a certificate issue? It works fine if I allow insecure content via info.plist, but of course I don't want to allow that.

The cert is fine for that domain. I'm unable to share the url unfortunately. It's a .gov domain. The cert is DigiCert and not-expired.

It works fine in Safari outside of the app, and even in Firefox and Chrome, which I thought used WKWebView but maybe not?

Has anyone ever experienced this issue? What additional steps can I do to pin down what exactly WKWebView is complaining about and what can be done to fix it?

We're actually using Xamarin, but we have test projects in both Xamarin and Xcode that replicate the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I see the solution in answer of uwei in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888321/wkwebview-give-error-intermittently-with-webpageproxy-error-code-1003-in-ios-app

Answer (score 8):

I found the problem!

WKWebView (unlike Safari) requires that SSL certs support forward secrecy.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsexceptionrequiresforwardsecrecy

You can check if a cert supports this here:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

It's possible to disable it in info.plist but we've opted to ask the site owner to change their certs.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this while using WKWebView in SwiftUI with UIViewRepresentable. The workaround for me was to reload the page in in the WKWebViews delegate didFailProvisionalNavigation.

```
struct CustomWebView: UIViewRepresentable{

    var webView = WKWebView()

   ...

   func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator{
      Coordinator(self)
   }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        webView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }
   
    func reload(){
        webView.reload()
    }

   ...
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var parent: CustomWebView

    init(_ parent: CustomWebView){
        self.parent = parent
    }
  
    ...

     func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        self.parent.reload()
    }
}
```